# Ohm's law hold till what temp?

Tags: temperature, electrical-resistance, material-science, approximations

Is the Ohm's law verified to hold true at all temperatures?  If not, then till what temperature does the Ohm's law hold?

I think it is valid only till $0$ K and above. Am I right in my thinking?

Comment: Ohm's law is valid for Ohmic devices.

Comment: I think you can look for when the material has convection and diffusion. I think Ohm's law stops being valid when velocity dependent terms or terms involving the gradient of the number density becomes comparable to the terms proportional to the electric field. Ohmic devices have convection and diffusion that doesnt depend on electromagnetic fields. (I read something like that in Alan J. Grodzinsky. Fields, Forces, and Flows in Biological Systems. Garland Science, 2011.)

Comment: ... I read something like that on page 42. The equation looks pretty much like Lorentz force law plus convection plus diffusion.

Comment: (Or rather Lorentz force law * mobility plus diffusion plus convection. I think the Lorentz-y term was called migration flux.)

Comment: @Emil I am afraid that I do not have access to the book that you have quoted from but to me convection implies a temperature difference and diffusion a concentration gradient? With the Lorentz force present there must be a magnetic field.

Comment: @Farcher I found similar reasoning on [this company's page](https://www.comsol.com/multiphysics/what-is-ionic-migration). There is also a similar formula on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst%E2%80%93Planck_equation). None of what I wrote were quotes... I only pointed to a book I read some pages in when researching for my master's.

Answer (score 1):

Ohm's law is a statement regarding the relationship between potential difference and current - they are proportional to one another.
What one can do is to decide whether or not for a particular object that relationship between potential difference and current is followed.
Whether or not an object follows Ohm's law makes no difference to the statement which we call Ohm's law.

So there can be no verification of Ohm's law rather one can test whether or not an object obeys Ohm's law.

Comment: You are right, but it is clear that this question is not about terminology, instead the op would like to know when usual objects obeys Ohm's law.

Comment: @Spirine I understand your comment but only the OP can rephrase the question. My answer is that Ohm's law is true for all temperatures.

Comment: The question is exactly about terminology. The OP thinks _Ohm's Law_ is like _Newton's Laws_ or _the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics_ - some fundamental law of naure. In fact, as you state, it's a handy observation that holds for certain useful devices in the range of conditions we use them. We should call it _Ohm's Rough Rule of Thumb for Resistors_.

Comment: @OscarBravo how about George's guess...

Comment: According to Purcell *Electricity and Magnetism*, Ohm's Law is taken as "the linear relationship between current density and field", ${\bf J} \, \alpha  \, {\bf E}$. Writing ${\bf J}  =  \sigma {\bf E}$  defines the conductivity, with Ohm's Law effectively being restated as $\sigma$ is a constant. The question is really asking about the constancy of $\sigma$.

Comment: Need more space for comment:  As well, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law states: "Ohm's law states that the R in this relation is constant, independent of the current. Ohm's law is an empirical relation which accurately describes the conductivity of the vast majority of electrically conductive materials over many orders of magnitude of current. However some materials do not obey Ohm's law, these are called non-ohmic."

Answer (score 0):

Ohm's Law states that

> Current passing through a conductor is directly proportional to the voltage applied across it provided temperature doesn't change.

As we can see, the law isn't concerned about temperature or a "*valid temperature range*" as long as it is kept constant.

After all, it's a law and the material being used may not follow the law if it breaks down or melts at very high temperatures.

However the prime necessity is that the conductor should follow *ohmic* behavior.

There are many such devices like diodes, transistors etc. which don't follow Ohm's law.

So, being concerned about the nature and conditions of material of the conductor is more important than being concerned about the temperature for checking the validity of Ohm's law as long as the temperature is kept constant.